# Using bootstrap popover in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

I like to use Popover in my AngularJS application and have included ui-bootstrap for this, but I get an injection error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ui.bootstrapProvider <- ui.bootstrap
```

In my index.html

```
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js"></script>
```

In my controller class:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('TeamsController', TeamsController);

TeamsController.$inject = ['Flash', '$scope', 'ui.bootstrap'];
function TeamsController(Flash, $scope, $modal) 
{
 //Code here
}
```

I cant really figure out how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You have to include it as a dependency to your app:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

More info on the [Angular UI page](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

**Update**

Working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pKRAX98dV8E99KhGQTHw?p=preview). Note that I have removed the `Flash` dependency because I don't know what it is, you must add it yourself back in the script.

Comment: I tried this, 'angular
    .module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('TeamsController', TeamsController);'  but then my site would not load at all...

Comment: What version of angular are you using? And there are any console errors?

Comment: No errors at all, just no page... using code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/oLRP76D8hsz9mt95Pz74?p=preview) plunker? It's also on the Angular UI page..

Comment: I did, tried some more, but got rid of it when updating my angular-version, hopefully I can get it to work now! Thanks!